# How can I improve the performance of my game that plays a video?

Tags: unity, performance, optimization, video

I have a level where I have embedded 5 short videos and the levels lags a little compared to the other levels, so it seems that adding videos in a Unity made game is expensive on its performance and memory.

Is there a better way to do this unity, maybe using GIFs or something?

Comment: There's a lot of factors that can negatively impact performance, the best place to start would be profiling your code / project to identify processing &/or memory spikes.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the kind of video you're using, and how it's being used in your level? Information on the video format can help too.

Comment: I think i'm going to try to use sprite sheets instead, firstly they take a little less space and maybe they perform better i have to check.

Comment: @Pikalek all my other levels are pretty much the same, i only notice frame drops on this particular levels with the videos.

Comment: @DMGregory I'm using  5 roughly 3 MB mp4 videos all being 360p

Comment: Are all the videos on the screen at the same time?

Comment: It might also be worth it to experiment with different [video formats](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VideoSources-FileCompatibility.html), video codecs and encoding settings. Perhaps you can find a setup which is faster to decode.

Comment: You'll probably have fewer follow-up questions to deal with if you **edit your question** to show us a sample of how these videos appear in your level, in addition to the settings you've tried using. This can also help us focus answers on strategies that will work well for your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I tried a few different methods, turns out instead of using .mp4 I can use .ogv, this results in a little bit of quality loss, but it made it extremely small in size, so the issues with the memory are fixed.

Also i now don't feel any frame drops at all in-engine, things should work even better outside.